# Why is no second PGP possible?

Tags: encryption, gpg, pgp

I've a problem with the command "gpg --gen-key".
At my very first time, I connected an eMail-Account to this and everything worked fine. I can use it and so on.
No Problem.

The problem is: I want to connect a second eMail-Account with a second Key and started the same command in the same way ... but NOW it tells me:

```
gpg: no writable public keyring found: eof
Key generation failed: eof
```

There is a folder: /home/accountname/.gnupg/
In this folder are several datas ... don't know if everything is like before the first key-generation.

What is the problem?

Comment: Permission problem? Are the files in `~/.gnupg` owned by the correct user?

Comment: Yes. I didn't changed anything. I do exactly the same like I did in the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add another mail address to the existing key.

Open a Terminal and type:

```
gpg --edit-key foo.bar@bar-foo.com
```

GPG comment line opens up, enter the following:

```
adduid
```

In the next step you can add another Name, Address and Comment.

Confirm you action with `o` and `Return Key`.
Save changes with `save` and `Return Key`.

Now you got another mail address added to your key.

The next thing to do now is setting the trust level for the new identity.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not being able to comment, I try to frame my approach as an answer...

Try to check whether the issue relates to your current .gnupg folder. For that,

```
mv .gnupg gnupg-backup
```

Then try

```
gpg --gen-key
```

again to generate your second key.

If that works, then try to import your old files

```
gpg --allow-secret-key-import gnupg-backup/secring.gpg
gpg --allow-secret-key-import gnupg-backup/pubring.gpg
```

At this point I would recommend you backup your .gnupg folder anew.

```
cp -r .gnupg gnupg-backup_2_keys
```

You can then also try to copy old configuration files, if you have them, e.g.

```
cp gnupg-backup/gpg* .gnupg
```